# Indexing with 'OR'

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

If I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM example.example_table et
 WHERE et.key1 = 10 OR et.key2 = 10
```

For this query, performance wise is it better to create two separate indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX example_table_key1 ON example.example_table(key1);

CREATE INDEX example_table_key2 ON example.example_table(key2);
```

Or a single index:

```
CREATE INDEX example_table_key1_key2 ON example.example_table(key1, key2)
```

Or does it simply not matter?  I'm leaning more towards two indexes.

For an `AND` I know it's better to use the latter.

---

What about in the case of a more 'complicated' query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM example.example_table et
 WHERE et.key1 = 10 OR et.key2 = 10
   AND et.key3 = 10
```

I've heard somewhere that having an `OR` is the same as writing the following:

```
SELECT *
  FROM example.example_table et
 WHERE et.key1 = 10
   AND et.key3 = 10
 UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM example.example_table et
 WHERE et.key2 = 10
   AND et.key3 = 10
```

This makes sense to me, in which case I'd imagine the following two indexes would be optimal:

```
CREATE INDEX example_table_key1_key3 ON example.example_table(key1, key3);

CREATE INDEX example_table_key2_key3 ON example.example_table(key2, key3);
```

But I'm not sure having an index on key3 twice would help... so in that case would you create one index for all 3 keys?

```
CREATE INDEX example_table_key1_key2_key3 ON example.example_table(key1, key2, key3)
```

---

I know a table with 3 keys is generally bad practice (especially if it requires an `OR`), but for my real life example I did not design the database.  Also the tables are not indexed... Code and other tables also rely on these tables so changing the design could effect production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OR gives notoriously bad performance,  because for each table access, only one index is chosen. Putting both columns in an index doesn't help, because the entire index must be scanned to find column 2's values.

Use separate UNIONed queries as you have suggested. Or if duplicate rows aren't going to happen, use UNION ALL which gives better performance due to not having to dedup.

Comment: Or use a bitmap index if it makes sense for your use case. Or partition the table, or use a hash cluster, or... I believe there are very many options that strongly depend on the size of the table and distribution of the data in the columns. But yes, generally, your answer is the best in general terms.

Comment: What if I'm dynamically generating SQL and I need the OR?  Am I stuck with this performance hit?

Comment: @Mocking Unfortunately, you're stuck with it.

Comment: @Mocking if it's dynamic, you can build up the query with `UNION ALL` as easily as you can with `OR` - just a little more string manipulation...